# Writing inner product of Hessians as a sum of inner products.

Tags: differential-geometry

Given an orthonromal frame $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$ and two functions $f$ and $g$ on $M$. Can we write the inner product of the Hessians of and and $g$ in the following way
$$
\langle \nabla^2f,\nabla^2g\rangle:=\sum_{ij}f_{ij}g_{ij}=\sum_i\langle\nabla f_i,\nabla g_i⟩ 
$$
at least when the referential is geodesic at a given point or is the last equality above never true on a manifold? Here $f_{ij}$ are the coordinates of the Hessian of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose your frame so that $\nabla_{i} e_j = 0$ at a point of interest, then we indeed have $$ \langle \nabla^2 f, \nabla^2 g \rangle = \sum_{i,j} \nabla_j (\nabla_i f) \nabla_j (\nabla_i g)=\sum_i \langle e_i f, e_j f \rangle$$ at that point. In general, however, $$f_{ij} = \nabla_j (\nabla_i f) - \nabla_{\nabla_j e_i} f$$ (as in my answer to your previous question) and thus there will be extra terms involving the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: Does this imply on loss of information or this is a kind of situation where this is allowed?

Comment: @Myself: I don't understand what you mean. This formula holds only  at a single point in a frame adapted for that point. It's never true in a neighbourhood or for arbitrary orthonormal frames unless the metric is flat.

Comment: My question is, for example, if we can integrate this formula like $\int_\Omega\sum_{ij=1}^nf_{ij}(\Delta f)_{ij}  =  \int_\Omega\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\nabla f_i,\nabla(\Delta f)_i\rangle$ and use integration by parts.

Comment: @Myself: you can certainly integrate by parts but you probably don't want to write anything in special coordinates to do so. The product rule gives $\langle \nabla^2 f, \nabla^2 g \rangle = \operatorname{div} (\langle \nabla f, \nabla^i \nabla g\rangle \partial_i) - \langle \nabla f, \Delta \nabla g \rangle$.

Comment: Anthony Carapetis, if we had just one derivative (the gradient) the formula $\int_\Omega\sum_i f_i(\Delta f)_i=\int_{\partial \Omega}\sum_if_nf_{ii}-\int_\Omega(\Delta f)^2$ where $\{e_1,...,e_{n-1},e_n\}$ is an adapted frame to $\partial \Omega$ and $e_n$ is the outward normal to $\partial\Omega$, would be true because it doesn't depend on the referential, yes or no? In your last commet, what does $\nabla^i\nabla g$ mean?

Comment: That equation is valid in any such adapted frame. You can replace $\nabla^i$ with $\nabla_i$ if you're working in an orthonormal frame. It's probably easiest to do this in abstract index notation - start with $\nabla_i \nabla_j f \nabla^i \nabla^j \Delta f$ and you can apply the product rule as usual. Just be careful about switching the order of derivatives; e.g. $\nabla\Delta f - \Delta \nabla f$ will be a non-zero curvature term.